# replace tabs with ',' from a .csv file using PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

I am new to PowerShell. I have a .csv file where data is separated by tabs. I want to replace all tabs with ',' using PowerShell.

One more thing, some columns **do not have data**.

I tried this but got error.

```
get-content file_name.csv | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '`t',',' } > changed_file.csv
```

> Error : **A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   arguments '$null'**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Reading a CSV file is done with [`Import-CSV`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) cmdlet. Since Powershell 2.0, one can use parameter `-Delimiter` to specify whether field separator is something else than a comma.

Use [`Export-CSV`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) to save the modified CSV. By using built-in cmdlets, all the CSV parsing and heavy lifting is done already.

The proposed way of replacing single char might give unexpected results. Consider a file like so and assume fields are separated by tabs,

```
Id    Name    Data
1     Tom     "Big boss"
2     Dick    "Senior Engineer"
3     Harry   "QA<TAB> Manager"
```

As the `<TAB>` character appears within the data column, the naïve approach of search and replace would create a fourth column like so,

```
Id,    Name,    Data,     Huh?
3,     Harry,   "QA",     "Manager"
```

Which would wreck havoc on further CSV processing.

The built-in CSV cmdlets parse the file as actual CSV data, so there is no mixing up columns on the wrong position - assuming the source CSV is well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

Just like vonPryz aldready answered. You would want to do something like this:

```
Import-Csv old.csv -Delimiter "`t" | Export-Csv new.csv -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks @Kirill for reply. But i am getting "Error : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts arguments '$null'".  i more thing **some column in file does not have any data(null).**